# Mocking method chaining with Mockito (especially a JPA TypedQuery)

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

I have a lot of code like the sample below that I need to test with Mockito.

```
return entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("queryName", Type.class)
    .setParameter("foo", "fish")
    .setParameter("bar", 42)
    .getSingleResult();
```

I have already injected a mocked EntityManager and have it return a mocked TypedQuery, etc. The problem is that I need to specify a rule like the following for every method in TypedQuery in order to have the test run successfully without NullPointerExceptions.

```
when(mockedTypedQuery.setParameter(any(String.class), any(Object.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockedTypedQuery);
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did in that case, was totally inspired by this post: http://geeks.autotrader.co.uk/2014/03/mocking-fluent-interfaces-with-mockito.html

I had the following service:

```
public class TestService {

    public TypedQuery typedQuery;

    public List test(){
        final TypedQuery typedQuery1 = typedQuery.setParameter("a", "a");
        return typedQuery1.setParameter("b", "b").getResultList();
    }
}
```

And my test case was:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChainMethodsMockTest {

    TypedQuery mockedTypedQuery = fluentMock(TypedQuery.class);

    @InjectMocks
    TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void testMockito(){
        final ArrayList value = new ArrayList();
        value.add("a");
        value.add("b");
        Mockito.when(mockedTypedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(value);
        final List test = testService.test();
        Assert.assertEquals(2, test.size());
    }

    public static <T> T fluentMock(final Class<T> type) {
        return Mockito.mock(type, Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(
                new ReturnsEmptyValues() {
                    @Override
                    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                        Object defaultReturnValue = super.answer(invocation);
                        if (type.equals(invocation.getMethod().getReturnType())) {
                            return invocation.getMock();
                        } else {
                            return defaultReturnValue;
                        }
                    }
                }));
    }
}
```

fluentMock method that you can share and reuse among your project(s).

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I believe that MockQuery must be stubbed out, because the TypedQuery must remember the parameters. Afterwards, then a doAnswer could work.

Comment: The fluent Mock resolution worked for me.Thank you @Manuel